# This "IF" won't work for me. Why?

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written the following code:

```
function test() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var testModeStatus = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Students").getRange("P2:P2").getValues();  
  if (testModeStatus == 'FALSE') {
     ui.alert("This is inside IF and Test Mode Status is "+testModeStatus);
    };
    ui.alert("This is outside IF and Test Mode Status is "+testModeStatus);
};
```

In the above code the variable `testModeStatus` refers to a sheet cell that is a checkbox and can have the value of either `TRUE`(checked) or `FALSE`(unchecked).

I want the code inside `if` to run only when the checkbox is unchecked. But no matter if the checkbox is checked or unchecked, the code inside `if` never runs and in both cases just the code outside `if` runs.
Moreover, in both cases the variable `testModeStatus` shows the correct value in the popping alert message. I mean if the checkbox is checked the variable shows `TRUE` and if it is unchecked the variable shows `FALSE` in the popping alert message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're comparing apples with oranges

`.getValues()` returns a bi-dimensional array and `"FALSE"` is a string.

Since you get a cell, you can use `.getValue` instead, but do note that GAS parses the boolean into a JS boolean, so, ultimately, the code should be:

```
function test() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var testModeStatus = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Students").getRange("P2:P2").getValue();  // getValue, not values
  if (testModeStatus == false) { //false, not "FALSE"
     ui.alert("This is inside IF and Test Mode Status is "+testModeStatus);
    };
    ui.alert("This is outside IF and Test Mode Status is "+testModeStatus);
};
```